# How to make a Go url bar in html+css

Tags: javascript, html

Im a noob at js, and I would like to make a go bar like at the top of browsers in html and js. It will go to the url in the box when the button is pressed nothing more, nothing less. Heres about what i want:
[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I haven't tried because I don't know js all i have made is an input type ="text" and a button

Comment: write a click function which will fetch data from input and you can use `window.open()` to reroute.

Comment: Your edit makes it so much more specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you just have to add an event listener in the "Go" button.

Then when you click the button, you just have to redirect the url according to the text field value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="field" />
    <button id="myBtn">Go</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var url = document.getElementById("field").value;

            window.location.href = url;

            // OR

            window.open(url);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code, if you enter a value in the text field and click the button. The url will add your value at the end.

For example if you are testing on the url localhost/ and you enter "test", javascript will redirect you to localhost/test.

To redirect correctly you *must* write "http://" or "https://" at the beginning

Comment: if you are using window.open, then why are you setting url `window.location.href = url;`

Comment: @Rajesh I wanted to show the different possibilities